# Generalized Likelihood Ratio Test with null hypothesis defined by union of sets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio, nested-models

Suppose you have a model with likelihood $ \mathcal L(\theta;\boldsymbol X) $, where $\theta \in \Theta$ are parameters and $\boldsymbol X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n ) $ denotes i.i.d. data.

[Likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Definition) considers performing hypothesis testing for:
$$\begin{aligned}
 H_0&: \theta \in \Theta_0 \\
H_1&: \theta \in \Theta,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Theta_0 \in \Theta$; it is therefore a nested hypotheses scenario. It proceeds by defining the following quantity (which is a random variable as it depends on $\boldsymbol X$):
$$\lambda_\text{LR} = -2 \ln \left[ \frac{~ \sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \mathcal{L}(\theta;\boldsymbol X) ~}{~ \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} \mathcal{L}(\theta;\boldsymbol X) ~} \right]$$

and defining an appropriate critical region using the above quantity. A useful result is [Wilks' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27_theorem) which shows that, as the sample size approaches $\infty$, then $\lambda_{LR}$ asymptotically approaches the $\chi^2$ distribution under $H_0$; moreover then number of degrees of freedom of the asymptotic $\chi^2$ distribution is given by $p = \dim \Theta - \dim \Theta_0$.

[I know this statement is not completely rigorous and glides over the fact that the exact parameter value has to be in the interior of $\Theta$ and some other technicalities. This is not the focus of my question however]

The above seems to work fine when, for instance is a single value as for instance $\Theta_0 = \{\theta_0\}$, for some $\theta_0 \in \Theta$, for which for instance $\dim \Theta_0=0$. Alternatively, if for instance $\dim \Theta = 2$, you can think of $\Theta_0 = \{\theta = \phi \cdot \boldsymbol a, \text{ for } \phi \in \mathbb R\}, $ for some fixed $ \boldsymbol a \in \mathbb R^2 $, which is a straight line and has therefore dimension $\dim H_0 = 1$.

But my question now is: what happens if, for instance $\Theta_0 = \{\theta_1, \theta_2 \}
$ for some values $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in \Theta$? Or if, instead, $\Theta_0 = \{\theta = \phi \cdot \boldsymbol a, \text{ for } \phi \in \mathbb R\} \cup \{\theta = \phi \cdot \boldsymbol b, \text{ for } \phi \in \mathbb R\}$, for some fixed $ \boldsymbol a, \boldsymbol b \in \mathbb R^2$? To me, it seems reasonable that, for the sake of Wilks' theorem, it'd still be sensible to take $\dim H_0 = 0$ for the former case and $\dim H_0 =1$ in the second. I'm not sure if that is the case however, neither if the theorem is applicable in such scenarios.

More generally, let say $\Theta_0 = \Theta_0 ^{(1)} \cup \Theta_0 ^{(2)}$, where possibly $\dim \Theta_0 ^{(1)} \neq \dim \Theta_0 ^{(2)}$. What do you take then as $\dim H_0$ in Wilks' theorem? Is the theorem still applicable in this case?

I think a path towards an answer could start from considering that
$$ \sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \mathcal{L}(\theta;\boldsymbol X) = \max \left\{ \sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0^{(1)}} \mathcal{L}(\theta;\boldsymbol X),  \sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0^{(2)}} \mathcal{L}(\theta;\boldsymbol X)  \right\};$$
but the maximum of two random variables does not have the same distribution as each of the random variables; so, even in the case $\dim \Theta_0 ^{(1)} \neq \dim \Theta_0 ^{(2)}$ I am not sure how to proceed here.